# How to fix error by creating new ssh connection?

Tags: c++, arm, raspberry-pi3

I m trying to cross-compiling a simple HelloWorld app in C++ on Win 10 for raspberry pi3. I installed toolchain to configure it out. But till now by creating new ssh connection i got always an Error such as "Access denied" or "No connection could be made bcz the target maschine actively refused it".

I checked many tutorials to cross-compiling but no success till now

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing different stuff here.

Cross compiling means compiling (and linking) the software for the embedded target **on** the host computer (in your case Win10). You don't need to SSH on the target for this. You'll likely need to run your configure your build like this:

`./configure --host=arm-linux --build=amd64-pc-linux-gnu`

The host argument is where the binary should run, and the build argument is where the binary is built.

However, I *suspect* that you've successfully built the software on your Win10 computer, and then you're trying to copy it on the embedded device. In that case, you must make sure that:

1. The embedded device is connected to the network
2. It's running a SSH daemon (likely `opensshd`)
3. It's allowing your user to connect to (typically, on default installation, `root` is not allowed to connect, you'll need to modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to `PermitRootLogin` to yes)
4. (Optionally) You generate a key pair on the host (via `ssh-keygen` and copy the public key on your embedded user's `.ssh/authorized_keys` folder) to allow password-less login

Please refer to SSH man page.

With all the above in place, you can then `scp build/mySoftware root@myDevice:/usr/local/bin` without the `Access Denied` message.

Comment: I guess you right. But still i am extreamly confusing, pls make me clear. I wrote hello.cpp on my Win 10. with my subsystem linux i can compile and run. but how to do then? @xryl699 will be apriciate

Comment: You need a cross compiler (for example, use Linaro's arm cross compiler), then type `/path/to/arm-linux-g++ -o hello hello.cpp` (you are compiling using the cross compiler). The resulting binary (`hello`) will not work on your system but will on the RaPi3, so `scp hello root@mydevice:/root`, test via `ssh root@mydevice ./hello`